# How to identify bottleneck using performance test results

Tags: performance-testing

I would like to know the process of identifying bottle necks using load runner test results.Can anybody throw some light on this topic?

Thanks,
Ramesh

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid this question is much, much too broad for Stack Overflow, which expects questions to be specific and very focused. I would start by Googling  things like `(name of your technology / platform) performance testing bottlenecks`

Answer (score 0):

Start here ->> http://www.perfbytes.com/performance_analysis

Unless you are monitoring your finite resources to find out where you have a resource impingement during an unacceptable time of performance you will have zero hope of finding where the bottleneck is located.